# MongoDB execution time of Aggregate Query

Tags: mongodb, profiling, database

I am trying to find execution time for an aggregation query.Query is like below:

```
 db.table.aggregate([{$sort: {count:-1}}]);
```

it sorts the 100K documents by count desc.The command line did not show all the records so i did the following instead:

```
 db.table.aggregate([{$sort: {count:-1}}]).toArray();
```

I have done db.setProfilingLevel(2);

when I run first query and do :

```
 db.system.profile.find((),{millis:1});
 I get millis : 18
```

when I run second query and find time from profile

```
 I get millis:18 , millis:87 , millis: 81 ... millis:75, millis:35. I get 12 different execution times.
```

I wanted to know if i want to correctly measure the execution time of aggregation where I order the whole collection by count desc. What is the proper way. Is the query with .toArray() the correct query for measuring execution. Can you please help me on how I shall measure the execution time.

Comment: I would not use `.toArray()` since that means it's going to actually "fetch" everything from the database. It doesn't really have any effect on what goes into `system.profile` but the "fetch" time is not actually the "execution" time, which is what the profiler records. Only use `.toArray()` if you are actually looking for a total time from submission until fetching the results. And of course the only valid timing would be by starting a timer before execution and measuring the difference after. It's all a bit "iffy" anyway. Your query and aggregate are "apples" and "oranges" here as well.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by query and aggregate are apples and oranges. Secondly if I need to measure only the time for execution by starting a timer before and after execution how shall I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query log level to 1. This will reduce lot of clutter. Now execute your aggregation query and look for `protocol:op_command xxxms` against your query in log file.

in my case, I'm executing

```
var cursor = db.doc.aggregate([{$sort:{_id:-1}},{$group:{_id:null, count:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

This query returns cursor and it's log entry appears as

```
2016-03-24T00:00:52.590-0400 I COMMAND  [conn7] command test.doc command:
aggregate { aggregate: "doc", pipeline: [ { $sort: { _id: -1.0 } },
{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1.0 } } } ], cursor: {} }
keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:5431 reslen:127 locks:{ 
Global: { acquireCount: { r: 10934 } }, Database: { acquireCount: 
{ r: 5467 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 5467 } } } protocol:op_command 1497ms
```

Please see at end of query operation in log. This will be your execution time without iterating over cursor.

Comment: I don't think explain gives the execution time

Comment: No it does not give the execution time.

Comment: I know profiling gives the execution time but I am not sure if toArray() would increase the time or not. The execution time shall be minimum because I am running a similar query on similar data set and structure on SQL Server. Sql gives me around 450 ms. If i sum up all the times I get by running aggregation().toArray() the average time comes to be around 750 ms. Is it normal?

Comment: Hi Saleem can you explain the query as to why you added $group in the end ?

Comment: Sure, Just to simulate query is taking long time and server is working hard on it. It's a demo query and you can replace it whatever your query  is.